# How to do proper dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am trying to do dependency injection in a single webjob, but I am a bit confused, I don't think I am doing it correctly.

For this project I am using Azure Cognitive Search, for this to work I need to set some variables in appsettings.json

```
  "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "MyKey",
  "AzureWebJobsServiceBus": "{SBEndoint}",
  "QueueToIndexDocumentsFrom": "{QueueToIndexDocumentsFrom}",
  "SearchServiceName": "{SearchServiceName}",
  "SearchServideAdminApiKey": "{SearchServideAdminApiKey}",
  "SearchServiceIndexClientDocuments": "{SearchServiceIndexClientDocuments}",
  "SearchServiceIndexJobDocuments": "{SearchServiceIndexJobDocuments}",
  "SearchServiceIndexBillCycleDocuments": "{SearchServiceIndexBillCycleDocuments}",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "{StorageAccount}",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "{StorageAccount}"
  },
```

With some of these variables I need to instantiate the object SearchClient and 3 objects (SearchIndexClient), but this must be done only once for the entire lifetime of the webjob

So I created the following code:

```
  public interface IIndexer
    {
        SearchServiceClient CreateSearchServiceClient(IConfigurationRoot configuration);
        Task IndexClientDocument(ClientDocument document, ISearchIndexClient indexClientDocument);
        Task IndexJobDocument(JobDocument document, ISearchIndexClient indexJobtDocument);
        Task IndexBillCycleDocument(BillCycleDocument document, ISearchIndexClient indexBillCyckleDocument);
    }

 public class Indexer : IIndexer
    {
        private string searchServiceName;
        private string adminApiKey;
        private string index;
        ISearchIndexClient indexClientDocument;


        // Create the search service client
        public SearchServiceClient CreateSearchServiceClient(IConfigurationRoot configuration)
        {
            searchServiceName = configuration["SearchServiceName"];
            adminApiKey = configuration["SearchServiceAdminApiKey"];
            SearchServiceClient serviceClient = new SearchServiceClient(searchServiceName, new SearchCredentials(adminApiKey));
            indexClientDocument = serviceClient.Indexes.GetClient(configuration[""]);
            return serviceClient;
        }

        public Task IndexClientDocument(ClientDocument document, ISearchIndexClient indexClientDocument)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task IndexJobDocument(JobDocument document, ISearchIndexClient indexJobDocumnet)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task IndexBillCycleDocument(BillCycleDocument document, ISearchIndexClient indexBillCycleDocumnet)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

and then in Program.cs I have the following:

```
 public class Program
    {
        private static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new HostBuilder();
            builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {
                b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
                b.AddAzureStorage();
                b.AddTimers();
                b.AddServiceBus(sbOptions =>
                {
                    sbOptions.ConnectionString = Configuration["AzureWebJobsServiceBus"];
                });
            });

            builder.ConfigureServices((context, s) => { ConfigureServices(s); s.BuildServiceProvider(); });
            builder.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                string appInsightsKey = Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appInsightsKey))
                {
                    // This uses the options callback to explicitly set the instrumentation key.
                    logging.AddApplicationInsights(appInsightsKey)
                            .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information);
                    logging.AddApplicationInsightsWebJobs(o => { o.InstrumentationKey = appInsightsKey; });
                }

            });
            var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken ct = tokenSource.Token;
            var host = builder.Build();
            using (host)
            {
                await host.RunAsync(ct);
                tokenSource.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

            Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables() //this doesnt do anything useful notice im setting some env variables explicitly. 
                .Build();  //build it so you can use those config variables down below.

            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("QueueToIndexDocumentsFrom", Configuration["QueueToIndexDocumentsFrom"]);
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SearchServiceName", Configuration["SearchServiceName"]);
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SearchServideAdminApiKey", Configuration["SearchServideAdminApiKey"]);
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SearchServiceIndexClientDocuments", Configuration["SearchServiceIndexClientDocuments"]);
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SearchServiceIndexJobDocuments", Configuration["SearchServiceIndexJobDocuments"]);
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SearchServiceIndexBillCycleDocuments", Configuration["SearchServiceIndexBillCycleDocuments"]);

            #region RegisterServiceProviders
                services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
                services.AddScoped<Functions, Functions>();
                services.AddScoped<IIndexer, Indexer>();
            #endregion

        }
    }
```

How can I create the instances of:
SearchServiceClient and the 3 ISearchIndexClient into one single place and make the code more readable?

Comment: what is Independency Injection. I am seeing first time

Comment: DI ,,,,,,.......